# Interface members to validate string variables

Tags: typescript, types

Let's say, I have an interface like this:

```
interface field {
    code: string
    name: string
    // ...
}
```

Then I want to create a variable with a value that only accepts members from that interface:

```
let key: "code" | "name" // ...
```

It will be a very wide line of code if there are many interface members, is there a solution for this?

Is there a quick solution to validate a variable based on the members of the interface using TypeScript as above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the use case for the [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) type operator:

> The `keyof` operator takes an object type and produces a string or numeric literal union of its keys.

```
interface field {
    code: string
    name: string
    // ...
}

let key: keyof field;

key = "code"; // Okay
key = "other"; // Type '"other"' is not assignable to type 'keyof field'.
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAhsCAbAJsg3gKGSOQQHssIAuZAZzClAHNDiQ4BbK2+plogen7IAdKPwBffPgwQwyANYQAntUVLSMVOmwBuKWuQBeZACIyFEzuSDkAeXlwl+A8ZOkwAC2iXrQgCpKAA4oAORunt4hyMA0yCDuyHA0NMCMbABGMshgpNlBoWoaWphYIcL4QA)